# Delete a sharepoint farm and rebuild

Tags: sharepoint-server, central-administration

I am just starting out to build a new production farm in 2016.

I put my Central Admin on a WFE server in SharePoint 2016 farm instead of an APP server - how do I delete the farm and start again?
Do I need to?

Answer (score 1):

If you run the config wizard on the WFE that is hosting Central Admin, you will have to option to remove Central Admin from the server in the wizard.  Then all you need to do is run the wizard on the APP server and have it host the central admin site.

On a side note I would not recommend using SP2016 for a new farm, I'd strongly recommend SP2019.  SP2016 will hit end of life first so you will get a few more years out of a SP2019 farm before you have to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You can [remove the servers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/remove-a-server-from-a-farm-in-sharepoint-server-2016) (except WFE) from the farm by running the Configuration Wizard/using PowerShell/using Central Administration, and then [uninstall SharePoint product](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/uninstall-sharepoint-server-2016) from each server.

Or you can just remove the servers by uninstall SharePoint directly using Control Panel.

However, uninstalling SharePoint product does not really “clean” the farm/environment for you. It is generally easier and more effective to build a new VMAs instead.